# script to login to the master server then its nodes

Tags: shell

I need to write a script to log in to master server with `ssh` and use `fuel node` command to view nodes and then connect to its node Respectively to view the log file of all the nodes that is in `/var/log/nova-all.log`

```
t.ex
node a 192.168.1.2
node b 192.168.1.3
node c 192.168.1.4
```

I tried to do this

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4

do

ssh -t "*masterserver name*" ssh $i | cat /var/log/nova-all.log

done
```

It is stuck in first node and doesn't do anything.

Comment: master server can be any name ,,,,i want to connect to the nodes a.b,c and show the log file of all them

Comment: It would help if you can add your code, so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you want your master server or your local host to connect to your nodes?

Comment: from my lockal host want to connect to master server first then to the nodes,, i cant connect to the nodes direct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your approach doesn't work out is that the pipe will be interpreted by your local system. Thus only `ssh $i` (with `$i` replaced by te respective IP`will be executed on your master server.`cat /var/log/nova-all.log` will be executed on your local machine instead of sent through the master server for execution on the subnodes.

If you local shell **and** the shell on `$yourmasterserver` is `bash`, something like the following should work:

```sh
ssh $yourmasterserver <<\EOF
for subnode in $(fuel node | awk '{ print $3 }')
do
  ssh $subnode cat /var/log/nova-all.log
done
EOF
```

`<<\EOF` starts a [HERE document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), which will be terminated by `EOF`. The backslash in `<<\EOF` causes substitution to be turned off, so that the HERE doc content is literally

```
for subnode in $(fuel node | awk '{ print $3 }')
do
  ssh $subnode cat /var/log/nova-all.log
done
```

These four lines will be fed to `ssh $yourmasterserver` as standard input (stdin). `ssh` passes whatever it receives on stdin (except for some control sequences) to the remote shell for execution. (That's why in interactive mode, you can just type in stuff for the remote site to execute.)

`$(...)` will be replaced by the output of executing its content. This execution will happen on the server, as (due to the protection mentioned above) the line will be sent to `ssh` as-is.

`| awk '{ print $3 }'` gives you the third column of the output of the preceding command (here, your `fuel node`). The `for` loop iterates over the result, using each element in it as `$subnode` in the loop body to connect to that node and `cat` your logfile.

Comment: thanks alot for ur answer. as i understand i will save the four line in a file. will i save this file in my host on masterserver?

Comment: Nope, no files involved. A 'here document' is not a file, it is a temporary document written on the command line and used as stdin by some command there. Just type (or paste) all 6 lines of the first code block into your shell and they should work. (If I didn't make any mistakes. I can't test them, as I don't have access to your server.)

Comment: so i will just copy the six lines in command line then the four lines will automatically save in here document?

Comment: Yes, except they won't be saved. (Here documents are something temporary and volatile. They only live in-memory and only as long as your command line needs them.) The four lines will simply become the input of the first line.

Comment: its working now,, but can you help me to make output like this format: ddmmyy hh:mm:ss node-xx PROCESS LOGLEVEL MESSAGE

Comment: That is probably worth a separate question. Feel free to link it here in the comments, if you post a new one concerning this.